# bash read timeout from serial port

Tags: bash, serial-port

I'm trying something like [Linux serial port listener and interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990702/linux-serial-port-listener-and-interpreter)

However, I want a timeout

```
#!/bin/bash
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB1 300 cs7 parenb -parodd
echo -n -e 'Sending '
echo -n -e "\x2F\x3F\x21\x0D\x0A">/dev/ttyUSB1
read LINE -r -t1 </dev/ttyUSB1
echo -n "Read "
echo $LINE
```

I'd like to continue if I do not get input; it just hangs.

(It is part of an input routine for reading a powermeter https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/305745/ir-data-from-landisgyr-e350)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16436335/2037061), I think you can use the [timeout](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) function to get what you want.
You'll probably have to do a bit of formatting and redirect the file to stdout, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37341961/2037061), so it would look like this :

```
LINE="$(timeout 1 cat /dev/ttyUSB1)"  
echo -n "Read "  
echo $LINE
```

You can also just use a combination of sleep and kill, like [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508467/bash-timeout-on-read-command).

Comment: I couldn't get read from serial to work, so I did this instead:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/305745/ir-data-from-landisgyr-e350/344460#344460